# VB.NET how to check if a webpage exists

Tags: vb.net, html

Is it possible to  check if a webpage exists or not in vb.net application ?

Comment: yes, what have you tried?

Comment: I have no Idea how this can be done .

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by requesting the webpage in question and looking if there's an error message.

```
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest
    Dim res As System.Net.WebResponse

    req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/werwerfsdfsdf")

    Try
        res = req.GetResponse()
    Catch e As WebException
        ' URL doesn't exists
    End Try
```

Comment: and how can I add IF statement in this code , like if this webpage doesn't exist then msgbox("Doesn't exist") ... ?

Comment: You can have a boolean and set it to false if the exception if throwned.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Private Function RemoteFileExists(ByVal url As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Method = "HEAD"
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        response.Close()
        Return (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: this worked for me as i didn't want to get the full data and Ping was returning unknown host so +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the text of a web page.

```
string strUrl = "http://forum.codecall.net/external.php?type=RSS2";


WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

string data = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an "If" statement to test for the non-existence. Simply plce the code to handle that eventuality immediately after the "catch" statement.
That code will only run if an error occurrs in the search ("WebRequest"). The error is when the page is not found.