# How to ckeck web page or exists or Not in .net...?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webrequest

I just want know the web page is connected or not without using WebResponse class becuase if i use this class its taking time to get repsonse. So i just want without using like this below code

```
    Dim url As New System.Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.CreateDefault(url)
    request.Method = "GET"

    Dim response As WebResponse
    Try
        response = request.GetResponse()
    Catch exc As WebException
        response = exc.Response
    End Try
```

Comment: `Without using WebClient or WebRequest`? Why? I suppose you could call a buddy and ask them to check and see if the webpage there. But if you're going to do it from code, why not use the libraries?

Comment: Error 404 exist for a reason :)

Comment: There's already an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385798/vb-net-how-to-check-if-a-webpage-exists

Comment: would just Pinging it suffice? `new Ping().Send("www.google.com").Status;`

Comment: So you want to check that it exists...without checking that it exists because that would take too much time?  That does not make any sense.  Any means of checking requires some sort of request & response, which takes time.

Comment: You don't need to `GET` the whole page, you can just use `HEAD` to see if the page exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't without using the proper classes for it, or writing your own.

My two cents: just execute the `HttpWebRequest` and check if the resulting HTTP status code is not 404:

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest q = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(theUrl);
    HttpWebResponse r = (HttpWebResponse)q.GetResponse();

    if (r.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        // page does not exist
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    HttpWebResponse r = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;

    if (r != null && r.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        // page does not exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a basic socket connection to the given server and the desired port (80). If you can connect, you know that the server is online and you can immediatly close the connection without sending or receiving any data.

EDIT: My answer was of course not really correct. By connecting to the server on port 80 just verfiys that the server accepts request and not if the specific web page exists. But after connecting you could send a GET request like `GET /page.html HTTP/1.1` and parse the answer of the server. But for this it will be much more comfortable to use WebRequest or WebClient.

Comment: Socket connection, could you explain more how a socket connection would solve this?